# OpenLDAP - Access rights by group

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

How do I grant

- full access (add, modify, delete)
- on the *children* of `ou=Something,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`
- to the *members* of group `cn=Managers,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com`

?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ServerFault. As stated this seems like a homework problem, or an attempted solution to a broader problem (see XY problem). Could you provide more context?

Comment: We need an LDAP account for managing only some accounts, not all the organization. The accounts to be managed are under `ou=Something,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com` and `ou=SomethingElse,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`.